# How to check current value on range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add the current range slider number on the range slider circle. I want my below range slider like this [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/13jormi).

```js
$(".slider").on("change", function() {
console.clear()
  var max = $("[name=plan]:checked").data('max')
  var total = 0
  //get total
  $(".slider").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val()) //calculate total
  })
  console.log("Total --" + total + " Max --" + max)
  if (total > max) {
    $(this).val(0) //set value to 0 again..
    console.log("can't move..")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="starter" name="plan" data-max="12" value="starter" checked>
<label for="starter">Up to 12</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="plus" name="plan" data-max="24" value="plus">
<label for="plus">Up to 24</label><br>

<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider">
<output class="range-text">
<span class="number"></span><span class="text">Videos</span>
</output><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you: https://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/ ?

Comment: Otherwise, if you have the time and patience, there is a long article here: https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on [jQuery Range Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Custom handle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handle.text( ui.value );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution by css-tricks.com, edited by me might help you. Unfortunately, you cannot position the 'bubble' over the default slider handle because then you can't click on the handle. In my opinion, it looks fairly good, and if you edit the slider styles themselves I think it could be very convincing.

If you want to make it exactly like in the screenshot, however, I really recommend reading [this article by css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input/) as it really goes in depth about creating a custom slider.

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
var bubble = document.getElementById('bubble');

range.addEventListener("input", () => {
  setBubble(range, bubble);
});

setBubble(range, bubble);

function setBubble(range, bubble) {
  const val = range.value;
  const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
  const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
  const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 100) / (max - min));
  bubble.innerHTML = val;

  bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${8 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
}
```

```css
.range-parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 3rem;
}

.range {
  width: 100%;
}

.bubble {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

body {
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-parent">
  <input type="range" class="range" id="range">
  <output class="bubble" id="bubble"></output>
</div>
```